# Portable HDD/SSD that can backup directly to Cloud (Google Drive)

Tags: wifi, ssd, hard-disk, wireless, nas

Looking for a portable drive (or just enclosure I can add a drive to) that will connect directly to a computer ideally via USB-C but then can also sync the contents of the drive via its own WiFi connection to Google Drive.

All the WiFi enabled drives/enclosures I’ve found so far only use the wireless functionality to read/write data to the drive itself.

It ideally needs to be portable. I know I may have to look at NAS I can find such as the QNAP HS-264, however that doesn’t have built in wireless and it’s very pricey.  TIA

Comment: Hi Josh, welcome to Hardware Recs! Is there a particular reason you can't just plug it into a computer now and then and have the computer upload the contents to Google Drive? Any solution we propose will basically be that but with extra steps.

Comment: Good question.  Won't always have that computer available.  So ideally if the drive gets passed around I know that whatever is dumped into a specific folder on it (or its entire contents) is auto sync'd to the cloud without requiring any manual intervention.  This QNAP NAS has a direct Thunderbolt 4 connection so could probably do what I'm looking for: https://www.qnap.com/en/product/tbs-h574tx, but it's $2000

Comment: And the drive definitely needs to be passed around physically, it can't be networked to the other computers that need access to the data? What are you storing on the drive, and what working environment is it in?

Answer (score 1):

**I think I might have just the thing you are looking for, it's basically a mini NAS and it's pretty powerful and should do what you need it to.**

---

> There are a couple different routes you could go with this and really depending how much time and/or money you have and if you like building your own gadgets etc.

---

1. RaspberryPI has some awesome creations and tons of resources from other users online and it's a massive community and honestly, who doesn't love a raspberry pi. This [link](https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/nas-box-raspberry-pi-tutorial/) will take you to the Raspberry PI forums with a full tutorial on how to create a NAS for pretty cheap and it's a fun project where you can learn some cool stuff.
2. This is another travel NAS/VPN/Storage/etc. called the [ZimaBoard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BKL3R4HZ) that I had seen NetworkChuck using in one of his videos I will add the link of the video if I can find it again, but it's pretty straight forward.

Either way should be good for what you're trying to do and the DIY route is really neat if you like to tinker, I know some people actually 3d printed their own case and the project files are online as well, super cool and it might be a little cheaper than the Zima.
*Hope this helps you a bit, feel free to ask me anything else!*